# How to view dwg in 3D view - customer question

Tags: autodesk-forge

our customer has prblem with view dwg files in 3D: He can see dwg only in 2D, he can't see it in 3d view. His question is how to do it right: Must he use PUT request or translate to SVG ? Or is there any better solution ?

Regards,

Milann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading document, mention `'role':'3d'` as shown below.

```
var viewables = viewerDocument.getRoot().search({'type':'geometry','role':'3d'});
viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, viewables[0]);
```

Ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/#step-2-load-model-in-manifest